# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -33

Tags: java, frequency, huffman-code

I have a method to count the frequencies of a string and record the frequencies with the character in an array that records 2 parameters (freq and char). This is the code:

The error is at this specific line:

> this.frequencies[c - 'A' ] = new CharFrequency280(' ', 0);

```
private void countFrequencies() {
    //TODO 

    // Initialize the frequency of each possible character to zero.
    for (int a=0; a<message.length(); a++){
        char c = message.charAt(a);
        c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        this.frequencies[c - 'A' ] = new CharFrequency280(' ', 0);
    }

    // Count the frequency of each character.
    for (int a=0; a<message.length(); a++){
        char c = message.charAt(a);
        c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        this.frequencies[c - 'A'].incrementFreq();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely no JavaScript.

Comment: is `this.frequencies` an array or list of some sort because you are trying to create a `CharFrequency280` inside an element that might not existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have read in a space character, which is ascii 32.

`'A'` is 65. So we have: `c - 'A'` = `32 - 65` = `-33`.